# LLM with Vector Database: Prompt to list all stored documents

Tags: nlp, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, vector-database

Let's say I have a vector document database of recipes (not too many, 10 maximum). I want to query an LLM (like GPT) with a prompt like "Which recipes do you have?", i.e. a query to list all documents. How can I achieve this behavior with LangChain (or a similar tool)?

One direction of thought I have so far: Create a short summary or title with GPT every time a new recipe is stored as metadata and when such a query comes in return all the summaries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow following steps

1. ConversationalRetrievalChain its akindof cahin that will help you to convesation wit llm using your data(in ml it will be called RAG)
2. retriever : you need retriever for retrieving the relavent document from your vectors DB , if already langchain having number of retrievals u can used or u can customized

demo available here:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/data_connection/

3. call chain using your llm, memory(if you want to pass old history), prompt and retrival

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
memory=memory,
llm=llm,
# max_tokens_limit=42000,
# callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()],
retriever=elastic_retrieval,
)

result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})

here chat_history: its optional for you
query : Which recipes do you have?

you can follow above steps to sol your problem